# How can I draw 2 commutative diagrams inside each other?

Tags: tikz-cd

Here is the figure I want to draw:

> [image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- this is not your first question, so you already know, that is desired that you provide some MWE and description, where you stuck in it
- this is also not your first question about use of the `tikz-cd` package
- As starting point, where you must enter the correct content in nodes where it has not yet been written

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
\color{cyan}  W \ar[ddd,mapsto,cyan] 
    &   & \color{cyan} (C_1,C_2,C_3) 
          \ar[ll,mapsto,cyan] \ar[rr,mapsto,cyan] 
        &   & \color{cyan}\makecell[tl]{([C_1],[C_2],[C_3])=\\
                                        (H[\beta_1],H[\beta_2],H[\beta_3])} 
              \ar[ddd,mapsto,cyan,"q1"] \\
    & H^{zn}(x') \dar["(j_1)"]
        & D \lar \ar[r] \dar["q_1"] \rar
            & E \dar
                &   \\
    & F & G \lar \rar
            & H  &   \\
\color{cyan} V_{\beta} 
    &   & \color{cyan} C_1 \ar[ll,mapsto,cyan] \ar[rr,mapsto,cyan] 
            &   & \color{cyan} [C_1] = H[\beta_1]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the first 2 bullets you mentioned ..... Do you mean by this statement "As starting point, where you must enter the correct content in nodes where it has not yet been written" that I should give you the document class I am using?

Comment: @Happy, with "starting point" I mean that answer contain just a skeleton for your diagram, which you need to finish yourself.

Comment: @Zarko Hi, how do you use makecell i.e. where it begin and where it finished using the curly brackets. Very nice the drawing.

Comment: @Sebastiano, `makecell` is used on standard way with options `tl` (top, left): `\makecell[tl]{([C_1],[C_2],[C_3])=\\
                                        (H[\beta_1],H[\beta_2],H[\beta_3])}`  in the place of (top right) node.  Thank you very much for compliment!

Comment: when I plug the real value of E that I want, it is very large so that it makes the blue square not completely drawn in my page i.e. I lost the edge with the map q1 from it ..... do you have any suggestions for this? or any adjustment for the code?

Comment: @Happy, use smaller value for `column sep`, or use smaller font size, or rotate diagram for 90 degree (in landscape orientation) or combination of the first two suggestions.